# MSMQ queue with multiple processes reading

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, msmq

I had a MSMQ application setup where data was being pushed into one queue. Initially I only had one process reading from it and processing it. Since the volume has increased I started multiple processes to read from it which is basically a new instance of my original process. I do not see any errors but the performance has really dropped. My understanding is that each process will read from a queue and receive a new message that has not yet been processed and continue with that. Is this correct or is it possible that multiple processes could end up processing the same message?

```
    Dim q As MessageQueue
    If MessageQueue.Exists(".\private$\MsgsIQueue") Then
        q = New MessageQueue(".\private$\MsgsIQueue")
    Else
        'GS - If there is no queue then we're done here
        Console.WriteLine("Queue has not been created!")
        Return
    End If

     While True
            Dim message As Message
            counter += 1
           Try
                If q.Transactional = True Then
                    Thread.Sleep(2000)
                End If
                q.MessageReadPropertyFilter.ArrivedTime = True
                message = q.Peek(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20.0))
                message.UseJournalQueue = True
                message = q.Receive(New TimeSpan(0, 0, 60))
                message.Formatter = New XmlMessageFormatter
                                   (New [String]() {"System.String"})
                ProcessMessage(message)
                ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, are you sure that it is the queue reading that is actually causing the performance degradation? I would suspect that there is some other bottleneck in your pipeline as MSMQ is really good at handling reading from multiple processes/threads.

If I take a look at your code I would suggest the following changes:

- Why sleep for 2 secs if is a tx queue? Always use tx queues and move the call to Sleep to the catch block to have a wait interval if the queue is empty.
- Move the setting of the filter outside of the loop.
- Remove the call to Peek as it performs nothing of value.
- Use journal queue is only of use when sending messages. So remove it.
- Set the formatter on the queue instead and it will be used for all reads.

You should also wrap the call to Read and ProcessMessage within a TransactionScope where you also wrap ProcessMessage in another try/catch block. This way you can commit the read if everything went Ok in ProcessMessage or otherwise choose to abort the read or move the message to a dead letter queue.

Comment: thanks for your response; I took a look at it and applied your suggestions. After posting here I fired a couple more processes and eventually the queue has been kept empty with processes running smoothly so yes, it is actually handled to accommodate multiple processes easily.